# DAG: Exchange 2010 and 2013

Tags: exchange-2010, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012, exchange-2013, dag

I have a server 2012 box that is now running AD/GC/DC/DHCP/DNS/Hyper-V and exchange 2010.

The domain/exchange started on a sbs 2003 box that I recently demoted after transferring all roles to the 2012 box.

I would like to create a virtual machine in Hyper-V and install Server 2012 OS with Exchange 2013.

I would then like to setup a DAG between the physical machine running Exchange 2010 and the virtual machine running Exchange 2013.

If this is possible I would then like to migrate the VM to a different physical server in case the original 2012 host box ever goes down.

Is it possible to create a DAG in this scenario and if so does anyone have any fairly specific documentation they could point me towards.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, as a DAG needs to consist of Servers using the same version.

Please find more information here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638104(v=exchg.150).aspx